# how to know which NSArray is causing the exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, callstack

My iOS app is crashing with the following error message.  Basically, I am trying to access an array index that is not present.

How do I get Xcode to show me the exact array name on which I did the wrong operation (or the call stack leading up the crash)?

****Error message I see***

```
2015-11-05 09:24:38.509 firstCDapp[1165:734714] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x279c585b 0x39086dff 0x27958bdf 0x923f9 0x2be38d63 0x2be38e89 0x2be28df5 0x2be3d46f 0x2bbe35af 0x2baf5cc3 0x2b3bdb05 0x2b3b9201 0x2b3b9091 0x2b3b85b1 0x2b3b8263 0x2b3b1a1f 0x27988091 0x27986387 0x279867c5 0x278d90d9 0x278d8ecd 0x30c4eaf9 0x2bb622dd 0x93b35 0x397d4873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Thanks, the link was really good in explaining how to find the source of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an Exception Breakpoint -> right click -> edit -> Exception = Obj-c, this can help you to find the error

Comment: Use the Raywenderlich article pointed to by ready, that explains hoot setup the exception breakpoint.